# Is Roblox available on PS4?

Tags: ps4, roblox

Is Roblox available on PS4?
I see some hits with Google, but probably they are a scam.

According to Wikipedia, PS4 platform is "in development". If it's not released yet, is there any target date?

Comment: This seems like an incredibly simple thing to be able to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many times to try to get Roblox on PS4. Sadly it's not on the console at this time. Maybe in the future, it will get released on PS4.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will ever be released on PS4. Maybe if we are lucky.

Comment: Doesn't this answer repeat what I posted [4 weeks earlier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/315437/181240)?

Answer (score 9):

[This answer is now outdated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/404418/181240).

---

[A search on the PSN store](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/search/q=roblox) returns 0 results for Roblox, which means the game is currently not available for PS4.

[image: PSN search for Roblox]

Comment: Could be available for a different region :) (not saying that it is available at all.. just pointing out this possibility).

Answer (score 1):

Roblox is scheduled to release for PS4 on [October 10th, 2023](https://blog.playstation.com/2023/09/14/roblox-coming-to-playstation-on-october-10/).

Answer (score -4):

You  can play ROBLOX on the PS4 you need to go to google chrome and play it.
But some games are not  available on PS4 for right now because some games have not been  released yet.